# Previous Shutdown Cause: -2

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, crash, mac-pro, shutdown

We have a new Mac Pro (3.6 GHz) running MacOSX 10.9.3 that unexpectedly powers off.

We've taken it in for service twice and the Geniuses were not able to reproduce the issue and the hardware diagnostics didn't apparently turn up anything of interest.

If left running overnight it will often (usually?) be OFF in the morning (not asleep, **OFF**).

Here are the values of the power management settings (this doesn't mean much to me):

```
$ pmset -g
Active Profiles:
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
 standby              1
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 womp                 1
 autorestart          0
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 darkwakes            1
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                1
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        0
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         15
 standbydelay         10800
```

And here are the final lines I see in Console for the most recent failure, earlier today (**edit**: moved longer console snippet to gist because was over the limit for SE):

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/23d25bfc9e354bd2864b/raw/cd586347b041a1f3dee6ef46628983922a44e5da/Mac_Pro_Log_Unexpected_Power_Down

I have just discovered the `pmset -g log` command so here are the contemporary lines from that:

```
6/11/14, 10:09:59 PM EDT WakeRequests           PM scheduled RTC wake event: SleepServiceImmediate inDelta=3543.05                    
6/11/14, 10:10:15 PM EDT Assertions             PID 17(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "Network wake delay proxy assertion" 00:00:00  id:0xe00000aa7 [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]              
6/11/14, 10:10:15 PM EDT com.apple.sleepservices.sessionStarted SleepService: window begins with cap time=86400 secs                                  
6/11/14, 10:10:15 PM EDT DarkWake               DarkWake [CDNPB] due to ETH0/Network: Using AC                              45 secs   
6/11/14, 10:10:15 PM EDT Assertions             PID 17(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:00  id:0xe00000aa9 [System: PushSrvc SRPrevSleep kCPU]             
6/11/14, 10:10:25 PM EDT com.apple.sleepservices.sessionTerminated  SleepService: window has terminated.                                                  
6/11/14, 10:10:25 PM EDT                        Summary- [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU] Using AC                                          
6/11/14, 10:10:45 PM EDT Assertions             PID 17(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "Network wake delay proxy assertion" 00:00:30  id:0xe00000aa7 [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]             
6/11/14, 10:10:45 PM EDT Assertions             PID 17(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "Network wake delay proxy assertion" 00:00:30  id:0xe00000aa7 [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]             
6/11/14, 10:11:00 PM EDT Assertions             PID 17(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:45  id:0xe00000aa9 [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]             
6/11/14, 10:11:00 PM EDT Assertions             PID 17(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:45  id:0xe00000aa9 [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]             
6/11/14, 10:11:00 PM EDT                        Summary- [System: No Assertions] Using AC                                             
6/11/14, 10:11:00 PM EDT Sleep                  Maintenance Sleep: Using AC                                                           
6/11/14, 10:11:02 PM EDT SlowResponse           PMConnection: Response from com.apple.apsd is slow (powercaps:0x0)                    1996 ms       
6/11/14, 10:11:02 PM EDT WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: [proc=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance inDelta=7198] [proc=SleepServicesD request=SleepService inDelta=3598] [proc=UserEventAgent request=TimerPlugin inDelta=7882 info=com.apple.EscrowSecurityAlert.daily]              
6/11/14, 10:11:02 PM EDT WakeRequests           PM scheduled RTC wake event: SleepServiceImmediate inDelta=3598.04                    
Sleep/Wakes since boot at 6/11/14, 4:37:17 PM EDT  :242   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:241

Time stamp                Domain                Message                                                                     Duration    Delay     
==========                ======                =======                                                                     ========    =====     
UUID: (null)
6/12/14, 5:17:22 PM EDT  Start                  powerd process is started                                                             
6/12/14, 5:17:22 PM EDT                         Summary- [System: No Assertions] Using AC                                             
Sleep/Wakes since boot at 6/12/14, 5:17:22 PM EDT  :0   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:0
```

The Geniuses hinted that the reason that they might not be able to reproduce the issue could be due to an interaction between the PowerMac and one or more peripherals devices.

Currently connected devices are:

- older Apple Cinema Display (with DVI to Mini Display Port converter)
- Apple Optical Drive (USB)
- Apple Keyboard (USB)
- Apple Optical USB Mouse

**UPDATE:**

- This issue is still persisting under 10.9.4
- The running this diagnostic, suggested by Buscar:

> syslog -k Sender kernel -k Message CSeq 'n Cause: -' | tail | awk
>   '/:/{$4=""; print}'

I get this result:

```
Jun 25 10:54:41  kernel[0] <Debug>: Previous Shutdown Cause: -2
Jun 25 17:51:57  kernel[0] <Debug>: Previous Shutdown Cause: -2
Jul 1 11:55:50  kernel[0] <Debug>: Previous Shutdown Cause: -2
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you press the power button once and it powers on, it's not just frozen with a black screen?  Searching through your logs do you see any entries for "Previous shutdown cause" followed by a number?  I assume you've connected it to a different power source?

Comment: Yes, I press the power button and it powers on.  The power button is not lit glowing until we hit it.  Will search for "Previous shutdown cause" and report back shortly.

Comment: Today's Previous Shutdown cause is '-2'

Comment: Please report if you have any sharing set up ?

Comment: Try to turn `autopoweroff` to 0

Comment: @AllInOne - I'm still just commenting on this but I think your best bet is having Apple repair the Mac Pro.  There's no reference for this online but this is what was explained to me during Genius training and again later when working with engineering on an oddball case.  Shutdown causes that are 0 or greater are normal or user initiated.  Shutdown causes that are -1 or lower are indicative of a hardware failure, whether it be overheating or someone accidentally pulled the power cord.  I'd leave it with Apple for as long as it takes them to reproduce the issue, with clear instructions (cont)

Comment: @AllInOne - (cont) to run the machine under heavy stress (multiple Yes commands, Grapher, etc) for several hours/days until it shuts down.  At that point they can verify the issue and hopefully pursue it with internal Apple support, whether it be engineering or another department. It IS possible that one of your peripherals is causing the problem but I've never come across an issue with negative number "shutdown cause" that wasn't fixed by repairing/replacing the Mac.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Don't see an explanation of my Error Code there.  And have added Console log lines to a gist representing a full minute before the failure.

Comment: do you need/use wake on network ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes we need/use wake on network. We occasionally log on to the machine remotely.

Comment: @MrRabbit Feel free to add your comment as an answer. We are going to pursue this course.

Comment: I have been going true both of your logs. What we need is a log from the moment you close the lid till you open it, so we can see what is it doing in that period, it should be not much.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It looks like a trash can but there is no lid!  :-)  It's a Mac Pro.

Comment: We still don't have a fix for this issue.  Apple sent us a new power cord for us to try‽  Meanwhile we have just applied 10.9.4 witch claims to address issues with wake-from-sleep.  Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has decided that this is likely a hardware issue (tho they were not able to definitively identify it, they suspected the video card) and has agreed to exchange the unit for a new one.

Answer (score 2):

This is not normal `digest-service[105]: digest-request: user=[redacted]`

and this `digest-request: guest failed with 22 proto=ntlmv2`

Disable all and any Sharing! in Preferences- Sharing

The following does not harm:

- Restore system level permissions using Disk Utility
- Now restore the user level ACL's using the CMD-R (at boot) then select password reset option (but do not reset the password), instead choose ACL restore.
- Run this diagnostics in terminal

> syslog -k Sender kernel -k Message CSeq 'n Cause: -' | tail | awk
>   '/:/{$4=""; print}'

It will copy the result to the clipboard. Paste it here. If no result, the clipboard will be empty.

[Log file 1](http://pastebin.com/Ge6MVsL7)

Log file 2

Comment: Hi Buscar. Can you explain why it's not normal and how it may be causing the power off issue?

Comment: @njboot look at the log file.

Comment: Hi and thanks Buscar. Sorry, I overlooked your request that I run the syslog command earlier. Have just run it now and got an empty result, but it may now be too long since the incident for the log to still have anything of interest. We've had one additional occurrence of the issue since my original post but it was some time ago now.

Comment: Ah something was wrong with the pbcopy part of your script it seems.  I took that out and got the result we were looking for.  I will paste update my question above with the result.

Answer (score 1):

> Previous Shutdown Cause: -2

Shutdown cause **-2** suggests a hardware issue (such as [faulty logic board](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mbp-classic-previous-shutdown-cause-2.1026406/), [video card](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/136933/22781) or [RAM](http://www.howapple.com/question/17868)).

> [`vTypErr = -2, /*invalid queue element*/`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1559997-anonymous/vtyperr?language=objc) <sup>[source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8418950)</sup>

---

Here are general suggestions:

- [Reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and [Reset NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) (which you did).
- Run an [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).
- [Log a kernel panic](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201753).
- Install [*EtreCheck* app](https://etrecheck.com/) to Find serious problems on your Mac.

For other shutdown codes, see: [Are OS X shutdown cause and sleep cause numbers listed/explained anywhere?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126588/22781)