# Is there an index / explanation for Shutdown cause -63 in the system log?

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic, shutdown

I am using MacBookPro12,1 (early 2015 model) and it restarts randomly without any warning. In the log, I found this:

`2017-12-14 20:51:50  Previous shutdown cause: 5
2017-12-15 10:37:31  Previous shutdown cause: 5
2017-12-15 12:08:05  Previous shutdown cause: -63
2017-12-15 19:14:19  Previous shutdown cause: 5
2017-12-15 19:42:05  Previous shutdown cause: 5
2017-12-15 20:09:32  Previous shutdown cause: 5
2017-12-15 22:32:39  Previous shutdown cause: -63
2017-12-16 00:08:00  Previous shutdown cause: -63`

Any idea what might have caused it? I've looked up the cause code, but it didn't provide me any additional information and I couldn't find anything online.

UPDATE: Now I always get this shutdown problem after closing the lid and opening it again and logging in. It happens every time after 5-10 seconds of doing that.

Comment: Negative numbers are usually hardware.  I would start by running AHT (Apple Hardware Test).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC cord attached.

Comment: When I posted log lines like this a high rep user replied "I've never come across an issue with negative number 'shutdown cause' that wasn't fixed by repairing/replacing the Mac." https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134860/mac-pro-unexpectedly-powers-off#comment159850_134860

Comment: Related, but doesn't explain what -63 is: [Are OS X shutdown cause and sleep cause numbers listed/explained anywhere?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126588/are-os-x-shutdown-cause-and-sleep-cause-numbers-listed-explained-anywhere)

Comment: @Allan I did run Apple Diagnostics. It didn't find anything wrong. I also did a full system recovery after erasing the HDD. What I noticed is that, it didn't happen during the recovery process which took several hours. After the recovery though, it started happening again, but only after immediately waking up from sleep/login.