# Shutdown cause: -104

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, shutdown

I have Macbook Pro retina, model 2013. It started to randomly shut down for no apparent reason. The system log always contains this message:

> Previous shutdown cause: -104

I have tried to reset SMC and PRAM several times. It did not help. The [hardware test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) found no errors. I have tried to google the meaning of shutdown code "-104", but I could not find anything.

Can anyone please provide any info about what's going on and possibly how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Shutdown cause -103 has something to do with a battery under-voltage. Found at [this link.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126588/are-os-x-shutdown-cause-and-sleep-cause-numbers-listed-explained-anywhere)

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be battery related. It may be related to -103, however both indicate that you should check the battery. Try running the laptop from the charger and see if the laptop still unexpectedly shuts down. Also check to see if there are any spurious sensor readings for the battery using iStat Menus or equivalent which may indicate the laptop trying to protect itself by shutting down.

> **-103**
>   Battery cell under voltage detected.
>   Check battery.
>
> **-104**
>   *unknown*
>   Check battery.

<sup>Source: [Shutdown Causes](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/shutdown-causes/)</sup>