# Kernel Panic - Random Shutdown - Please Help

Tags: macos, kernel-panic, shutdown

Recently (the last three day) my late 2013 iMac has been suffering from kernel panics.
After reboot, console shows a 'Previous shutdown cause: -62'.
Can someone please tell me what this means.
The only thing I have changed is I added a new backup drive (2TB external).
It seem to only happen after about ½ hour after wake (from sleep).
It only does it when doing multiple processes, like running photoshop, iTunes open in background, youtube vids playing etc.
So, any ideas.
Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks, BR

Comment: Same as http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186094/kernel-previous-shutdown-cause-62-help-needed probably. Negative shutdown codes may indicate a hardware issue, try keeping your external drive unplugged for some days, or use a different cable, or a different port; and see whether the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before. You should back up your computer to the drive and re-install OS X, because this behaviour from an Apple device occurs when some system files are missing/corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

> Previous shutdown cause: -62

basically means:

> Watchdog timer detected unresponsive application, restarting the system.

So you're advised to troubleshoot your system for any stuck application, startup item and any loading preferences. Re-install macOS also may help.

<sup>See: [Are OS X shutdown cause and sleep cause numbers listed/explained anywhere?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126588/22781)</sup>