# My Mac is beeping 3 times every couple of seconds when it starts

Tags: mac

Here is what happens, I have 5-10 seconds to do stuff on my computer, then it turns off, turns back on again and attempts to load or something, then turns off. then eventually after enough on and offs, it goes to a white screen and beeps 3 times every couple of seconds, I searched it up, and it definitely doesn’t beep every 5 seconds but a little less than that. This only stops when I press the power button.

Note that I don’t know much of my computer, and I haven’t tampered with anything on the inside or inserted anything into the disc slot or anything. But from what I remember it is osX

Comment: What Mac do you have? If its a Mac, you most probably have some version of OS X/macOS installed. Can you confirm what version you're running (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201260)? Have you tried the different startup-modes (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255)?

Comment: Try running [Apple Hardware a Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Also, try to identify what Mac model you have with this [serial number lookup tool](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/).  The S/N will be on the bottom of your Mac if you can’t boot it.  Finally, if you can boot the Mac, try to obtain the [Shutdown Code](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234850/119271).  This will help us in determining the problem

Answer (score 2):

That does sound like ***"Three successive tones, then a five-second pause (repeating)"***, which according to Apple, suggests that the RAM has not passed an integrity check.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202768

You mention a disk slot, so it's likely quite an old Mac. The last models with optical drives were c. 2012, I think.

Either way, it's a hardware problem that needs hand-on, physical inspection by someone competent. See if there's a local guy who does Apple repair work. (The Apple Store may say it's too old, but it's worth a try.)

It may just need the existing RAM to be reseated or replaced. Or it may be a problem with the main circuitry: in which case it's time to go shopping.