# iMac 27” 2010 Black screen just after chime

Tags: mac

I’m having a problem on my iMac 27” Just after the chime it will show the loading bar then after a few seconds it just turns off so there’s no way I can get to use the keyboard.Is this possibly a power supply problem? I would appreciate some help.. Thanks
Thundereux

Comment: Turns off as in the screen goes black or it’s completely powered off.  The title and body don’t match, so it’s not clear

Comment: Sorry if it may sound confusing... After the chime comes the loading bar for usually 5 seconds then it just switches off...

Comment: That could be any number of things from the power supply to the logic board.  You'd need to get it professionally diagnosed because *something* is causing your power supply to shutdown.  However, just going on my gut, I think you're correct and that your [power supply is bad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230288/119271).

Comment: Thanks very much Allan for Your time and appreciated opinion..

Comment: No prob.  Let us know how things come about.