# The reason for Previous shutdown cause: -128

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, shutdown

My MacBook Pro 11,2 (Retina 2014) shuts down suddenly from time to time. When I run macbook again, I inspect the log file I see the following message:

> Previous shutdown cause: -128

Sometime, when I close a laptop, fans begin to hard work. It happens with/without power adapter. I launched Diagnostic and I got 'NO ISSUE'.

When I run macbook in SafeBoot, all work correctly, but very slowly.

I tried:

1. Reset SMC, PRAM.
2. ERASE Disk and install macOS from scratch.

Also, I tried to remove battery and use the power adapter only. In this case it work correctly, but sometime I get another error (It happens rarely).

Macbook pro 11,2 Retina 2014 (15 Display)
Intel Core i7 2,2 GHz
RAM 16 GB
SSD 256 GB

Comment: [Using any search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Previous+shutdown+cause:+128&t=osx) on this gives a lot of articles with potential solutions. Which of these ideas have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a Mac do a similar thing and it turned out to be the logic board. Unfortunately, you might have to take your Mac to the Apple Store or a computer shop for them to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

The shutdown cause -128 is related to the hardware issue. It may be related to RAM, although it can be also related to [battery time span](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/227702/22781) (it surpassed the end of its life).

<sup>See also: [Shutdown Cause -128](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/212809/22781) & [Are OS X shutdown cause and sleep cause numbers listed/explained anywhere?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126588/22781)</sup>