# Getting error code -128 on a late-2015 iMac

Tags: macos, imac, reboot

Late 2015 iMac is rebooting on its own. Only Finder running, OSX 10.11.6. (2) 8GB RAM sticks. Got to catch it in the act today.

After reboot I find
kernel: Previous shutdown cause: -128

That doesn't appear to correspond to anything useful in the old MacOS error codes documentation from 1998:

-128  userCanceledErr         User canceled an operation

http://www.macwizard.com/errors.html

The is a refurb unit, hoping it doesn't need to go back for another refurbishment.

thanks

Comment: Can you please reinstall MacOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precise meaning of the shutdown cause codes is not publicly documented, so linked error about *userCanceledErr* isn't correct, as these are different list of codes.

The shutdown cause -128 in general is related to the unknown hardware issue (e.g. RAM). If it happens repeatedly, you should take it to the repair.

See also:

- [Shutdown Cause -128](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/212809/22781)
- [Are OS X shutdown cause and sleep cause numbers listed/explained anywhere?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126588/22781)