# Random Kernel Panics with Shutdown Cause: -64

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic, shutdown

I'm using Retina Macbook Pro 15inch (OS X El Capitan 10.11.5) and getting random kernel panics frequently since March 2016. (1 or 2 times a day or more)

This is a company laptop and bought in October 2015, my company admin have sent in the macbook to Apple Authorized Service Centre but they say no issue found and return it after 1 whole month. After get back the kernel panic still remains.

He also performed several fresh installation of the OS X (downloaded from Apple) and still get kernel panic.

I'm not sure whether it is a software-related or hardware-related issue as the Apple Diagnostics didn't show any problem.

Things I've tried :

- Apple Diagnostic Test
- Fresh install of OS X
- Use EtreCheck (Report seems fine)
- Use iStat Menu Pro to check on the temperature (around 40 degree celsius to 80/90) When kernel panic occurs, it usually stay at high temperature like 90 degree +
  Does it means overheat causes kernel panic?
- Resetting the SMC

List of software/tools that I used :

- xcode
- android studio
- slack
- skype
- chrome
- source tree
- atom editor
- node, npm
- iStat Menu

But I still getting kernel panic every day...

If it is overheat, why it works normal before this? (from October 2015-March 2016)

If it is software-related issue, why after fresh install it still get kernel panic?

If it was hardware issue, why Apple can't find the root cause? >_<

---

I checked on the Console and found this (after kernel panic)

- Previous Shutdown Cause: -64

May I know what does this means? I search through other posts and all of them are -62, -128, 0, 3, 5 and etc... None of them are getting -64

Apple is not making the shutdown cause available to public as well >_<

Comment: [@grgarside's blog doesn't have an answer either](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/shutdown-causes/), and he's my go-to for debugging this. I'd like to know as well.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.macwizard.com/errors.html (I know it's _really_ old)

Comment: @Brick i think this is the mac error code not shutdown cause code... after format again, i'm getting shutdown cause -62 when kernel panic occur..

Answer (score 1):

From the details you provided. It sounds as if the kernel panic is due to to an issue in the firmware of your device. There are two things you can do:

(before doing any of the solutions, always have a backup of your files, especially the important ones)

1. Use the App Store to see if there is an update for your firmware. Just and fyi, you should update your system to the most recent version available.
2. Do a quick Google search on the firmware updates for your model. Download and install.

Worst case scenario: the motherboard could be failing. The apple diagnostic does not always give an accurate test if the hardware. The more in depth apple test is available to Apple Care repair services.

Best case scenario: all you have to do is SMC reset and a NVRAM reset.

Follow instructions for these resets here:

- [NVRAM reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)
- [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

If none of these options work, I would write down the panic error that is displayed in the text, and do a quick Google search for anything related to the panic error, i.e. why does (put panic error here) occur....