# macOS Sierra restarting download instead of resuming

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

macOS Sierra is a whopping 4GB+ download and on my capped bandwidth ISP connection I've wasted already 10GB just trying to download it. App Store always restarts download instead of resuming from how much it had already downloaded. I frequently get logged out (am guessing its because of heating issues) so the download is interrupted.

Am running OS X 10.10 on Macbook Air mid-2011 11" model.

Any help to fix this?

**Update** Here's the output of `syslog | grep -i "shutdown cause"`

```
Oct  5 15:24:17 leh kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 3
Oct  5 17:05:43 leh kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 3
Oct  5 17:53:43 leh kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 3
Oct  6 18:06:44 leh kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 3
Oct  6 23:32:49 leh kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 3
Oct  6 23:35:42 leh kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 3
Oct  7 23:18:26 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 3
Oct  8 11:46:24 leh kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 3
Oct  8 11:52:36 leh kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 3
```

From googling the shutdown code, I [saw](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/255401/90171) that 3 stands for a dirty shutdown. How do I investigate which app is causing a dirty shutdown?

Comment: I'm not sure how to resolve the issue itself but if you have a friend with better internet, or a library or something, you can download it and put it on a USB key.

Comment: Having your computer restart in the middle of a download is more than likely corrupting the download meaning it can't resume cleanly.   Let's see why your computer restarted.  Issue the following command in Terminal:  `syslog | grep -i "shutdown cause"` and post the results to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the app store cache to see if that fixes the issue.
http://osxdaily.com/2016/10/08/mac-app-store-temp-cache-folder/