# Auto shutdown at night after High sierra upgrade

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, security, upgrade

I upgraded to macOS High sierra and now my system shuts down automatically at night. This is quite annoying.

I tried looking in `System Preferences` > `Energy Saver` > `Schedule…` settings but, there's no schedule set.

Can someone please help me with this.

I am using MacBook Pro 15" Mid 2015

Comment: The only place I know that could be set to do that is.. System Prefs > Energy Saver > Schedule There was recently a question where someone found that was enabled without their knowledge.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, I have already checked it, it is not enabled.

Comment: Same problem here on a Touchbar MBP 15". Hoping a dot release fixes it.

Comment: couple of days back, I reinstalled "command line tools" and after that I haven't faced this issue, I don't know how they are related.

Comment: @banjara: How did you install this? Me too facing this problem !

Comment: @AkshayLokur you can download it from App Store.

Comment: @banjara Thanks for reply. I searched but App store does not return any results for "command line tools", do I need to search something else?

Comment: @AkshayLokur try 'xcode-select --install'

Comment: I checked the Schedule settings (which were off) and already have command line tools installed. Problem still persists on two machines. Most nights whilst in sleep mode, they do a shutdown. Occasionally they stay in sleep mode.

Comment: Could you add in your question if these "shutdown" happened on battery or power supply?

Comment: @drekka: do you still have these unsollicited shutdowns? Do they happen on battery or on power supply?

Comment: Nope, all been good for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing "command line tools" solved this issue. However, I have no clue how they are related.

To install command line tools run following command in terminal.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue each day since installing High Sierra. However, in my case, the computer doesn't shut down, but rather goes into deep sleep. I called AppleCare and they acknowledged the issue and said they are working on it.