# Compatibility of NVMe and deep sleep in Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, sleep-wake

Like many others in the community, I am running a Samsung NVMe drive in my Late 2013 15 inch Macbook Pro. [Thanks to the firmware update provided in 10.13 Macs back until around 2013 can work off of a NVMe drive natively] (Credit to Gilles) <sup>[1](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/upgrading-2013-2014-macbook-pro-ssd-to-m-2-nvme.2034976/page-6)</sup>.

I used a Chenyang NGFF to Apple 12+16 adapter and formatted the disk in Disk Utility in the installer to APFS, then installed the system (10.13, initial release).  Note that before wiping and reinstalling the OS, I had previously upgraded to High Sierra.

Speed wise I am getting about 1400MB/s read and write speeds. I am stating all of this to show that the drive itself works great, except for deep sleep mode feature. It cannot come out of deep sleep mode, it just shows a black screen. Anyone happen to know of a fix?  I have read that it could be due to the drive not powering on in time for the SMC to find it.  If no fix is likely, what workarounds are there? [image]

Comment: I don't think it's related to your particular setup.  This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/300361/119271) seems to imply that it's a known issue.  This [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/message/32312038) indicates the same symptom on a MacPro.

Comment: What drivers / firmware is on the NVMe and does the vendor have a patch / support for Apple controllers?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this. Before try, Please check yourself about pmset, and if you like this then try.

open Terminal in Utility folder in Application folder.

```
pmset -g
```

(a list shown that is pmset setting)

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0 standby 0 autopoweroff 0
```

(administrator password is needed)

This command makes a Mac never hibernate or deep-sleep.