# MacBook Air 2013 rebooting when waking up from standby

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, sleep-wake, reboot

I recently started having this problem with my MacBook Air 2013 (i7/8GB) running the latest High Sierra:

Sleep itself works perfectly fine. If I wake up the device within the standbydelay of 3 hours, there is no issue. As soon as the device goes into deep sleep (also called standby/hibernation?), for example if it was sleeping overnight, I get the following issue:

I see the Apple logo appearing shortly with a chime, then I get a line across the screen and the screen goes dark as if I forced the device to turn off. After that, the device chimes again and it boots normally but it doesn't go back to where I started. It seems to perform a full reboot.

I already tried disabling some sleep related features like Power Nap. I cleared my NVRAM and SMC. Apple Hardware Test completes successfully.

Anything else I could try here? Oh, and I use APFS Encrypted with File Vault 2. Could this be the culprit?

Comment: It sounds like your your sleep image is corrupted.  Try deleting `/var/vm/sleepimage` and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks, Allan. Weirdly, the problem still exists but I noticed the following: When I wake up the device shortly after it hibernates - say, 4 hours after closing the lid - it turns on and recovers the sleep image without a problem. Only on a longer sleep like overnight my problem still persists.

Comment: Is it plugged in or on battery?

Comment: It's on battery, but almost fully charged. Last night I closed the lid at 95% and when it rebooted today it was at around 90% so it's not an issue of power loss.

Comment: What I do want to add is that I use the DestroyFVKeyOnStandby setting in pmset. I have now turned that off and am decrypting my disk temporarily. I will report back tomorrow if that makes any difference.

Comment: You could possibly have a failing battery.  See this Q/A:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272910/why-does-my-laptop-shut-down-overnight/273084#273084  Check the shutdown cause in the log (see question for command to review log)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My battery does hold up very well as it has only 300 cycles but of course I won't rule out a defect since it's 5 years old. Since I just did a safe mode boot, my logs are cleared and every shutdown today was marked as 5. That is a good idea though, I'm curious as to what it will print out on my next overnight standby. I'll be in touch.

Comment: For now, it didn't happen again. I did all of the following: Deleted the sleepimage like you suggested, decrypted my disk, booted in safe mode to flush the caches, reinstalled macOS via Recovery and encrypted my disk again. For now I am leaving the DestroyFVKeyOnStandby setting turned off. I can't say what exactly fixed it but at least for now, it's working. Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: Next time, do one thing at a time so you can identify what the issue is and take a targeted approach next time there's an issue.

Comment: Absolutely, though since I am travelling next week I needed this to be sorted out ASAP.