# MacBook Pro frequently reboots

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, reboot

I'm going to describe the symptoms I'm seeing, diagnostic steps I've taken, then give the hardware configuration below. I would love to have any suggestions on how to fix this, or where to take my investigation next.

1. When the laptop starts "cold", i.e. it has not been used for a few hours, it is just fine
2. After a few hours of use (3 or 4), it will hard reboot itself. No error messages visible, no kernel panics found in the logs, as far as I can see.
3. After that, the hard reboots come more and more frequently
4. It appears that the machine stays on indefinitely if not used

UPDATED SYMPTOMS
Having charged the computer with an appropriate charger, the computer seems able to sustain more life and longer downloads. However, now the computer is experiencing screen glitching, especially related to vibration.

### Diagnostic steps

5. Suspecting this to be a temperature issue, I installed Fanny and put the laptop on ice (literally, on ice). Even with CPU temperature consistently below 50C, it still would reboot frequently.
6. Looking at the Console application, no messages about "kernel" "panic" "restart" or the like.
7. Booting into Ubuntu from an external USB drive has the computer working just fine, even if it gets hot.

### Hypotheses

9. Either a software problem under macos; or
10. An issue with the harddrive (or possibly some other hardware that ubuntu isn't activating)

### Hardware configuration

Macbook Pro (Mid 2014), 15.4 inch, 2.5 GHz, 16 Gb ram
Sierra 10.12.6 (Multiple upgrades over original).

## System.log

System.log only has entries mentioning shutdown at times corresponding to intentional shutdowns. Nothing for these hard reboots.

However, right before one of the hard reboots there's this:

```
Aug 26 23:39:53 Marcins-MBP-2 filecoordinationd[381]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source
 cancel handler was invoked
Aug 26 23:39:53 Marcins-MBP-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemor
yLimit
Aug 26 23:39:54 Marcins-MBP-2 gamed[964]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked
Aug 26 23:40:13 Marcins-MBP-2 hidd[116]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked
Aug 26 23:40:31 Marcins-MBP-2 Console[324]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked
Aug 26 23:40:46 Marcins-MBP-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Aug 26 23:40:46 Marcins-MBP-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imtranscoding.IMTranscoderAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamPriority
Aug 26 23:40:46 Marcins-MBP-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imtranscoding.IMTranscoderAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Aug 26 23:40:46 Marcins-MBP-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imdmessageservices.IMDMessageServicesAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Aug 26 23:40:54 Marcins-MBP-2 Dock[326]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked
```

## Apple Hardware Test

The only information it gives is that I have the wrong wattage of power adapter

## Resolution

I got the HDD and logic board replaced by Apple. The computer works now.

Comment: Version of macOS?  Also, in your system log, can you find a entry that says "Shutdown cause "?  Also, try running [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

Comment: @Allan thanks, updated. Will update again when the computer is stable enough :{

Comment: Best of luck...I know *exactly* what you are going through...I'll help as much as I can!

Comment: @Allan I have updated with what information I have been able to extract.

Comment: So upon rebooting it doesn't give an error of any sort? No [shutdown causes listed anywhere?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126588/are-os-x-shutdown-cause-and-sleep-cause-numbers-listed-explained-anywhere)

Comment: Is Sierra 10.12.6 the original OS, or was it an upgrade (over what previous version?) or clean install? How old is the MBP and when did the frequent reboots start? after any update?

Comment: @LangLangC Updated, mid 2014.

Comment: @smci Updated, definitely an upgrade over whatever version was out in mid 2014.

Comment: @JMY1000 Correct, no shutdown causes listed.

Comment: @Allan This is independent of displayed battery life, though. I'm going to run the diagnostic again, but I think this is also a "too much wattage" adapter.

Comment: "Displayed" battery life is just a calculation and not reliable. Secondly, "too much wattage" will never be an issue, having too little will.  You can use an 85W adapter on a device that needs 60W, but not the reverse.

Comment: @Allan Although it is independent of reported charge level, the charger is insufficiently powerful. I guess that should be my first port of call after trying the other issue you linked.

Comment: Perhaps for or against this diagnosis: triggering a big download (of the sierra installer) almost immediately triggers a reboot. Not sure if the ssd is a power hog or what. This is still consistent with the "linux never reboots" because it's not really using ssd. I guess the next thing is to try doing a big download under linux.

Comment: @Allan Also, doing a find -delete (to target the dotfiles in the other answer) in Mac resulted in a restart, then in Ubuntu in a core dump and everything freezing except the mouse pointer. If this isn't a power/disk interaction, I think it's the disk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64506/discussion-between-allan-and-marcin).

Comment: @Allan I'm leaning to this being a power issue. Having charged with the correctly rated charger, the computer seems to be working fine. I was able to download the whole sierra installer for the first time. Disk access seems not to be causing problems. Thank you!

Comment: @Allan Well, ironically the computer just rebooted itself again right after I posted that.

Comment: Any updates?  I've got very similar error messages.  This started immediately after I had a battery replaced (by Apple).  They also replaced some fans.  It tends to happen immediately after I click to change which application is active.  The computer freezes for a bit, and then turns off.