# Where to look for MacOS crash

Tags: crash

"Your Mac restarted due to a problem."

System.log showed boot time as 17:19 and the last message before was 17:13 but things had been working in the five minutes before the restart.

Six log files had file dates after 17:13, but five of them had **NO** messages before the reboot.  (The other has timestamps only in raw integer format)

So how do I look for clues to what happened between 17:13 and 17:19 ?

It's a Macbook Pro 2012 refurb still under warranty (purchased January) but the RAM and SSD were transferred from an older machine.

Comment: If I understand correctly you restarted the computer and it seemed normal, with the exception of that popup?

Comment: Seemed normal before it crashed, too.

Comment: Check for the `Shutdown Cause` code in your log and see: [Shutdown cause and sleep cause numbers listed/explained anywhere?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126588/22781)

Comment: Well, I am going to check the other question, because "check the log" is not a very useful answer to "where is the log?"